# '_TypeError' is not a subtype of type 'String' error Flutter Map

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get a Map<String, List> from Response

My Object is

```
    class Product{
      String id;
      String title;
      double price;
      String image;
      bool sc;
    
      Product({@required this.id, @required this.title, @required this.price,
        @required this.image, @required this.sc});
    
      factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return Product(
          id: json['id'] as String,
          title: json['title'] as String,
          price: json['price'] as double,
          image: json['image'] as String,
          sc: json['sc'] as bool,
        );
      }
    }
```

Http code goes here

```
    Future<Map<String, List<Product>>> fetchProduct(String url) async{
    dio.Dio d = new dio.Dio();

    Map<String, dynamic> headers = new Map();
    headers['Cookie'] = "JSESSIONID=" + SessionUtils().getSession().toString();
    dio.Options options = new dio.Options(
      headers: headers,
      contentType: 'application/json'
    );

    dio.Response response = await d.get(url, options: options);

    print(response.data);
    if(response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok){
      return json.decode(response.data); // need help here
    }
  
  }
```

I Got the error `I/flutter (20085): Another exception was thrown: type '_TypeError' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

THANKS!

Comment: can you find which line in `Product` class creates this error? the error is probably from id,title or image

Answer (score 0):

[API Reference for DIO](https://pub.dev/packages/dio#dio-apis)

In their API reference, they have mentioned that you have to set a responseType in the options. The default is JSON so maybe you can directly return response.data because it's already been deserialized into a map.

The other option may be:

```
responseType = responseType.string;
```

in dio options and then you will get response.data in the string form which you can manually decode.

I have never used DIO but as per the API reference, this seems to be the problem because the error suggests json.decode() expected a string but got a map so maybe response.data is dynamic and the data type changes based on the responseType specified. Give it a try!